# Installing C compiler, JDK etc. in Ubuntu

Tags: installation, software-center, openjdk, c

I am a new to Ubuntu. I have used Windows before, but I am not able to install new software in Ubuntu from the offline setup files, so I don't know how to install software in Ubuntu. Please tell me how to install new software, such as C Compiler, JDK, etc. in Ubuntu.

Comment: c compiler is already installed by default...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java 6/7 JRE or JDK?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-6-7-jre-or-jdk)

Comment: Asking how to install "C Compiler, JDK, etc" is rather broad. It would be preferable for you to specify exactly what you are trying to do and ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are preparing to build software, then

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

is a good place to start - installs your basic C and C++ compilers, libraries and utilities, all in one operation.

There are several JDKs that can be installed from the standard repos (make sure you have enabled the partner repo in `/etc/apt/sources.list`). @Tarun showed above how to install `openjdk`, but see [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html) for how to install Oracle Java8.

Answer (score 0):

To install the softwares you have mentioned type the following commands in command line

For JDK:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

You can use the gcc compiler

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

For other softwares you can search via apt just type the command to list

```
sudo apt-cache search {software-name}
```

Or the best way for you to install a software is by using Ubuntu Software centre

See the link here

[Ubuntu Software Centre](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Software-in-Ubuntu)

Comment: but how to use GCC for C programming. I m in a habit of programming on windows using turbo c compiler. How to type and compile my c programs

Comment: If you need to know how to compile C programs in Ubuntu thats a different question look at the following link http://www.wikihow.com/Compile-a-C/C%2B%2B-Program-on-Ubuntu-Linux

Comment: gcc -Wall -W -Werror main.c -o HelloWorldC
gcc: error: main.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
anant@anant-desktop:~$    ..........this is the error i encounter while compiling a program

Comment: Well then I believe you put a new question for it giving all the details.

Comment: how to reduce brightness on my screen. It's straining my eyes